# ViewPager fragments are not shown in nested fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity with navigation menu (I am using android's `NavigationDrawer` class). The menu has N entries, each corresponds with one `Fragment` within the activity. On activity create, I do the following:

```
mFragment1 = new Fragment1();
mFragment2 = new Fragment2();
mFragment3 = new Fragment3();
...
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout1, mFragment1);
transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout1, mFragment2);
transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout1, mFragment3);
...
transaction.hide(mFragment1);
transaction.hide(mFragment2);
transaction.hide(mFragment3);
...
transaction.commit();
```

Then I make `mFragment1` visible calling `show`.

When user clicks the menu:

```
transaction.hide(mVisibleFragment);
mVisibleFragment = mFragmentN;
transaction.show(mVisibleFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Every fragment contains `ViewPager` with some other fragments and tab header. I use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as an adapter and build the pager in `onCreateView`:

```
 pager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

I can see `ViewPager`'s content only for the first menu (`mFragment1` had been shown initially). When I switch to another menu fragment, I can swipe pages and see selected tab changing, but I can't see pages themselves.

Can anyone point at my mistake and, most importantly, explain what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find my mistake.

I used `getFragmentManger()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()` in order to create `ViewPager` adapter.

Hope my solution helps someone.